# ADB more than one device/emulator but there isn't

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb

```
(master) $ adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
error: more than one device/emulator
(master) $ adb devices -l
List of devices attached
emulator-5554          device product:sdk_gphone_x86 model:Android_SDK_built_for_x86 device:generic_x86 transport_id:2
```

Trying to deploy a react-native app to an emulated device. The build, gradle etc runs fine but when trying to connect to the emulator it shows an error `more than one device/emulator` despite there only being one device when running `adb devices`

Literally no idea how to solve this, Android Studio 3.1, emulated device is a Nexus 5x running Android 8. Have restarted, upgraded etc but still get this message.

Comment: Are you by any chance running some docker containers on the host?

Comment: Also, since you mentioned react-native, are you sure adb isn't perhaps already connected to the emulator? Try: `adb -s emulator-5554 disconnect && adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` .

Comment: @John I wasn't running any containers at the time but I do have Docker installed. I removed the Docker interface I could see in `ifconfig` but that didn't seem to help yesterday. Oddly when I switched on today it now connects, so maybe it's the case that the network interfaces needed a reboot. A bit annoying that I will lose access to adb each time I use Docker - is there a know bug/solution here? Thanks

Comment: Very likely the build script issues an `adb connect <ip>:<port>` command that incorrectly connects to an interface installed by Docker at your end. Try using a different ip/port for react-native and the emulator.

Comment: Any news? How did you solve this

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu It seemed to be the case that removing the docker interface fixed it. I've since started using docker again but not tried ADB with the emulator. So whilst I have ideas I don't have anything I'd put my name to for a solution, unfortunately

Comment: That's works for me: `adb tcpip 5555`

Comment: Thanks to myself, I just made my day a year later :) It was a good surprise for me also.